# iMessage: How do I search for keywords in an individual message thread?

Tags: macos, ios, messages

I have a 5-year conversation going on with my wife on iMessage.

Every once in a while I want to find something like a restaurant she messaged me about.

I want to search for the word "restaurant" and find ALL the times she used that word, meaning only within HER messages.

How can I do that?

I know about the universal iMessage search, but that's not what I'm after. It shows me only 1 instance of the word "restaurant," not all of them.

Comment: I wish....  I've sent that suggestion to http://www.apple.com/feedback before, you should also.

Answer (score 8):

The archive of all the messages is in ~/Library/Messages/chat.db. It's a SQLite database. There are some SQLite viewers that will make it fairly easy to sort this data and either allow you to search it or selectively export some of it to CSV. A good example would be https://sqlitebrowser.org/ which is free and open source, it also allows for CVS export so you can open it as a spreadsheet.

Alternately if you search for "sqlite to csv" you'll find some more information on exporting it. Unfortunately this is a big weakness of iMessage.

Comment: Should get more upvotes. This isn’t a bad solution, intact it’s a very good one.

Comment: I would just edit and add a viewer that does this.

Comment: @user7886229 good call, added a link to a good SQLite tool.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Messages on Mac
2. Type term into search bar (also accessible using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
3. Click on the desired conversation you want to search in
4. You'll see the first message (chronologically) that contained the word displayed in a faded color
5. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see the next occurrence and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see the previous one.

--

Keyboard shortcuts are shown in the menubar: Edit → Find

This functionality should work across most apps, not just Messages.

Comment: This search functionality is very hit or miss and generally not reliable or effective. Also I'm pretty sure the original poster said this wasn't effective.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with both of your statements. Can you expand on your perceived lack of reliability/effectiveness?

Comment: I just tried searching for the words "Crash pad" that are in an iMessage from my dad dated 2 days ago. iMessage says "No results found" and a search for just the word "Crash" gives tons of results except for the message from my Dad. Not sure how much worse you can be at search than that.

Comment: is your Mac fully up to date? can you post screenshots?

Comment: Yes, I'd rather not take the time due to all the PII I'd need to blur out, and why, do you not believe me? It's not a problem I need a solution to, just the reality of using iMessage.

Comment: I don't think you're lying but I've never seen that behavior and I'm thinking that I may be able to tell you why you're seeing that behavior. Just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Sorry just don't see how seeing a screenshot is going to help you diagnose this problem, but I'm ready to be impressed. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zrit3rnxei98cl0/iMessage%20Fail.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing. So I ran some tests on my own. Initially I found that changing the capitalization a couple times fixed it ("crash pad"), but it wasn't reliable. What was reliable was quitting iMessage and then re-opening. My guess is that those messages hadn't been indexed yet (presumably because they're relatively new) and it re-indexes when we restart? Does that fix it for you?

Comment: Tried quitting repeatedly, changing caps, adding quotes, nothing works.

Comment: I agree. Search feature on this message app does really suck

Answer (score 4):

This was asked a long time ago, but Apple still didn't do anything to make the search in Messages easier or more reliable, and I just faced this problem myself today.

**The best solution I have found is to use *Chatology*** for Mac. It is a paid app (with a 14-days trial), but does the job perfectly:

- it allows you to search through entire single conversations,
- it searches for word-substrings, not just whole words,
- it ignores diacritics
- it has (optional) integration with native Messages app, so hitting <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Messages will automatically open Chatology for you.

Lastly, it allows you to export entire conversations as text files, so you can search them manually or do whatever you need to do with them.

You can download the trial or buy the app here: https://flexibits.com/chatology.

*Note: I am not related to developers of the app in any way.*

Answer (score 1):

Edit => Find => Find Next & Edit => Find => Find Previous are greyed out for me so those approaches aren't options.

I simply opened the conversation in a separate window and kept scrolling up rapidly to load all of the old chats.

You can press `command` + A to select the entire chat, press `command` + C to copy it to the clipboard, and then paste the chat in TextEdit (or another text editor).  Any text editor will provide better search support than iMessage - just press `command` + F.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac:
Open Terminal.

Browse to your Messages directory. Replace 'jimmy' with your username. If not sure, browse to the Users directory first to confirm what it is.
`cd /Users/jimmy/Library/Messages`

Next run a program that allows you to interact with the database containing your chat messages:
`sqlite3 chat.db`

sqlite program opens and gives you its own command prompt. Enter the following replacing the number with the number of the contact you want to search on.  Actual contact names like 'Jill' are not stored in the db, so you have to use their phone number (if that doesn't work, maybe try their email if that's all you have for the contact. Replace the example text, Apple, with your own keyword or phrase. Leave the % signs as they tell the program to search for the word or phrase at any location within the message like so:
`select text from message join handle on message.handle_id = handle.ROWID where handle.id = '+19344968775' and message.text like '%apples%';`

If you got the phone number right and there are results for your search you will see the content of the text on the next line, like so:
`Please buy apples`

To exit:
`sqlite> .exit`